# "new(...args: any[]) => T" vs "{ new(...args: any[]): T }"

Tags: typescript

What's is the difference between `new(...args: any[]) => T` and `{ new(...args: any[]): T }` and which one should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are aliases, and they both doesn't support static fileds:

```js
class X {
    static staticAttr = 42;
    static method() { }
    attr: string;
}

interface A {
    Attr1: { new (...args): X }
    Attr2: new(...args: any[]) => X
}

let fn = (arg: A) => {
    arg.Attr1.staticAttr // Property 'staticAttr' does not exist on type 'new (...args: any[]) => X'
    (new arg.Attr1()).attr;
    (new arg.Attr2()).attr;
}
```

`{ new(...args: any[]): T` is mapped by TS into `new(...args: any[]) => T`. So i think `new(...args: any[]) => T` will be better, but is no big difference

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20X%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20static%20staticAttr%20%3D%2042%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20static%20method()%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20attr%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Attr1%3A%20%7B%20new%20(...args)%3A%20X%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Attr2%3A%20new(...args%3A%20any%5B%5D)%20%3D%3E%20X%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20fn%20%3D%20(arg%3A%20A)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20arg.Attr1.staticAttr%20%2F%2F%20Property%20'staticAttr'%20does%20not%20exist%20on%20type%20'new%20(...args%3A%20any%5B%5D)%20%3D%3E%20X'%0D%0A%20%20%20%20(new%20arg.Attr1()).attr%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20(new%20arg.Attr2()).attr%0D%0A%7D)